# Jersey 2.10 in IBM WebSphere

Tags: jersey, websphere, java-7, jersey-2.0, websphere-8

I am setting up project with Jersey 2.10, JavaSE 1.7 in Websphere 8.5.5.2 (websphere 7.1 SDK)

When i deploy the project, i get this error

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)

I tried to delete the jersey libraries after deploying the project and map it to shared library (same jersey libraries) on websphere. The shared library is mapped to project now, but get other error when i run the application like below.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[RESTSrv01]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: Internal Server Error
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.commit(ResponseWriter.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
Any suggestion what could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8)

Comment: Check that other post how to replace use your own Jersey libraries.

Comment: I noticed Jersey has been initialized in the console when the server has started. I checked the class loading order in admin console. I did google and see the technote from IBM here [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21461909). Cleared the cache, but still see the second error in my posted question. I also checked the class loading order and it has been loaded only once.

Comment: Did you configured your shared library as 'isolated'? Are there any further exceptions in that stack trace (like caused by)?

Comment: I filtered out few unnecessary jar files, changed the SDK to 1.6 and got it working. Need to check it changing SDK to 1.7 and debug it when i have time. Thanks Gas!

Comment: You're welcome. Great that you manage to solve it ;)

Comment: I am having this same problem deploying to Websphere 7 and I can't seem to figure it out.  When you say you changed to SDK 1.6, do you mean all of your Java / Jersey endpoint code?