# Removing JAX-RS feature from Websphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: websphere, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have created a rest api using jersey 2.10 framework. The application is deployed on Websphere application server 8.5. Since websphere comes bundled with jax-rs 1 implementation, I configured shared library to use jax-rs 2 jar files. My company policy does not allow configuration of shared libraries and I am being asked to downgrade to jax-rs 1 implementation. And that is the last thing I want to do.

Is there a way to disable or remove jax-rs 1 from websphere 8.5. JAX-RS is included under web 2.0 features in websphere and is it possible to remove/disable web2.0 feature in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to use Jersey 2.10 framework is via shared library as discussed [JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in WebSphere 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713878/3701228). You could use WebSphere Liberty, where you can disable jax-rs 1.1 or WebSphere Liberty Beta, which supports JAX-RS 2.0. But with your company restrictions, it probably will be not possible also.

So for the future, you should know about benefits and limitations of the platform that you are planing to deploy and use its provided features instead of some third party, especially if you have some other external limitations.