# Deployed Rest Services in IBM WAS 8.5.5.4.Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes (initialization failure)

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, ibm-was

I Trying to deploy Rest Services in IBM WAS.But it is showing

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes (initialization failure)**

I am Using following jar
[image]

Please help to debug issue

Comment: WebSphere provides JAX-RS runtime, so you need to remove Jersey jars from your application and either use built in (Apache Wink) or configure third party provider as described here [Using Jersey with WAS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24713878/3701228)

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong.I tried to deploy same application in other WAS with same version it is working fine.

Comment: If you know better and have other working environment, then copy configuration from that environment.