# Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, websphere-8

I am new to writing webservices using Jax-RS. I took the *spring-cxf-rest-example* that is using CXF 3.0.0 and JAX-RS 2.0 to try a simple rest service.  This war runs fine in May Beta version of Websphere Liberty profile as it supports JAX-RS 2.0.  But I would like to run it is Websphere 8.5.5.1 that supports JAX-RS 1.1.  So I have disabled the JaxRS engine in the server. 
I am now getting the following Exception.  So What Jars am I missing.

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
```

the jars in my war are

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cxf-core-3.0.0.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.0.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.0.1.jar
jackson-core-2.0.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.0.1.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.0.1.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.0.1.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar    
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.3.0.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar
```

Comment: It would help to provide more details about the failure. There are other questions on stack overflow about CXF and Spring that reference that exception, but there isn't enough context to know if they are similar or not.

Comment: If you want to use your provider, you either need to create isolated shared library or change the classloader order AND disable internal engine. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24713878/3701228) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at that post. It talks about Jersey implementation. But doesn't CXF also provide the implementation? So what CXF jars do I need to put in the isolated Shared library?

Comment: Here is the extract from the exception stack  : org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException. ...Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:209)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:317)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:152)
 ... 40 more