# adding rest web service into websphere supported application

Tags: jersey, websphere

I already have an application which is deployed on websphere 7.X.
Now i need to add rest web service to this application, so i added jersey servlet related information in web.xml and deployed the code in tomcat,
I worked fine on tomcat, but the same war file when deployed on websphere it threw the below exception

```
10/29/15 16:07:55:203 EDT] 00000009 WebApplicatio I   Initiating Jersey   application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
[10/29/15 16:07:55:747 EDT] 00000009 FfdcProvider  W  com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted  on /opt/was7/app-it2/profiles/p-c7it2-a/logs/ffdc/as-c7it2-a-mfr-  3_59bd59bd_15.10.29_16.07.55.7124506202519276998895.txt   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 181
[10/29/15 16:07:55:749 EDT] 00000009 ServletWrappe E   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet "servletname" in application XXX: java.lang.VerifyError
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.  <clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:263)
            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)
```

I am very new to websphere and i am not able to find out why this exception is being thrown.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For WAS v7, install Feature Pack for Web 2.0 and check the following page how to develop JAX-RS. [Getting started with IBM JAX-RS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.web20fepjaxrs.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxrs_getstarted.html)

Comment: The mentioned page describes rest development using Apache wink, I am looking for jersey implementation and its support with WebSphere 7,X

Comment: @JuniadAhmed You could try procedure described here [JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8/24713878#24713878), although there are several limitations when you use third party jax-rs engine.

Comment: There is a very good chance you will need to upgrade from WAS v7 to something newer in order to get Java 7.

Comment: @Gas: I have some restriction as some third party software is certified on webSphere 7.x. Also JAX-RS support is not available with WebSphere 7.x, So i was hoping there will be no exception while deploying an ear/war file with jersery framework.