# Skip loading of a jar file in WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: apache, cxf, websphere-8

I am getting an exception as given below.
I want `Response` class to be loaded from `jawax-ws-rs.api.jar`.
but its getting loaded from the `j2ee.jar` and throwing the below error:-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object
```

Is there any way we can skip loading of `j2ee.jar` at startup of WebSphere?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incorrect, probably what you really want is to replace JAX-RS engine provided with WAS with some third part. And you should never pack `j2ee.jar` with your application as all required classes are already loaded by the server.

Check the following posts and links:

- [JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8/24713878#24713878)
- [Disabling the JAX-RS runtime environment](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_disable_runtime.html)