# Jersey rest lib from a war is clashing in WAS 8.5 and giving java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: rest, websphere, jersey-2.0

**Application Server:** Websphere 8.5

**Project Type:** It is a war project based on Restful Web services and created using jersey **javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar** and jersey libraries are shipping in **WEB-INF/lib**

We are installing and starting the project successfully. But when we are calling web services, we are getting following exception: -

```
000000c7 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Jersey RESTful Application]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:629)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
```

I have tried following link, but it has not helped.

[JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8)

Comment: If you can use WebSphere Liberty, it only exposes the features you want, so it's much easier to avoid this sort of class loading conflict.

Comment: If you can move to WebSphere v9.0, it is updated from jax-rs 1.1 to jax-rs 2.0 so has the method signature you need.

Comment: Have you set the classloader to load classes from your web application first (PARENT_LAST)?