# Deploying Jersey JAX-RS 1.1 application on WAS 9.0

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, websphere

I'm trying to deploy App bundled with Jersey 1.17.1 on WAS 9.0 and getting the CDIRuntimeException

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CannotBindObjectException: Object is not of any type which can be bound. Object type is com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:196)

I tried this already without success from the link below i.e.

- com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true
- Applications > WebSphere Enterprise Applications > {your.application} > Manage Modules > {your.module}, Change the Class loader order dropdown to: Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last).

[JAX-RS Jersey 2.10 support in Websphere 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8)

My goal is to use the war file as is with the bundled Jersey jars without having to create shared libraries. We are able to run this app on WAS 8.5.5 Is this not possible on WAS 9.0?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please attach a test app here or raise a PMR for further investigation?